# Keycloak user storage provider not visible in user federation

Tags: keycloak

I implemented a user storage provider for keycloak to get users from an external database the provider id is django-user-storage.
I copied the jar file to the providers directory and did a kc.sh build and then a kc.sh start

The log does not show any errors but I do not see the extension within user federation as described [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extension/user-storage-jpa). I would expect that I see another box with my provider id there.

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to make sure to have the file `org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory` present. I accidentally renamed this file and then the provider is not found.

From [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#packaging-and-deployment):

> In order for Keycloak to recognize the provider, you need to add a
> file to the JAR:
> META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory.
> This file must contain a line-separated list of fully qualified
> classnames of the UserStorageProviderFactory implementations.